# Custom setup project for "Setup and Deployment Visual Studio"- How to get the contents of the folder where the .msi file resides?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, setup-deployment

Does anyone know how to find the path of the installer while it is installing?

My goal is to get either none, 1, or 2 folders that are also in the same folder with the setup, and copy them to a destination the user chooses before installing. Those folders may or may not be there.

Through lots of pain I have found out how to use the custom actions through installer classes, and even with that its still ugly, but cannot go further unless I can check whats in the same folder with the installer. I'm about to throw a kitchen sink at how difficult the process is for making a custom setup.

Any help or suggestions in this matter will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be the `[SOURCEDIR]` property.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280749/getting-the-sourcedir-property-from-a-c-custom-action) may point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, I tried searching google and SO for bin, root, etc folders, but didn't think of Source.

Answer (score 0):

I am bit confused of your question, in my point of view if your problem is to copy certain folders or files to where you installed setup file its very simple.

1. Right Click  Setup (Project) > Click View > click File System.
2. A new interface is created.
3. Right click on the Application Folder > click Add > click Folder.
4. Specif a Folder name > Right click on the newly created folder > click Add > Click File.
5. Select all the file that you wants to be in the setup installation folder.
6. That's it. you are done.